# Problem: Background color of programmatic UI remains black

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I've created the UI of a modal that pops up when you press a Tab Bar Item within a Tab Bar Controller. This is the first time that I've accomplished this programmatically, so there may be something that I'm missing here, but I can't seem to change the background color of the modal at all. More specifically, I'm trying to make the background transparent, but it appears in black when the modal is presented, no matter what color I change it to. I'm not sure that it matters that I've programmatically added subviews to the main view (for example, a UIView called "titleContainer"), but want to note this here just in case.

Below is part of what I have in my code:

```
override func loadView() {
    view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.isOpaque = false
    
    titleContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 180))
    titleContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    titleContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    titleContainer.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    titleContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    titleContainer.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    titleContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(titleContainer)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        titleContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        titleContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        titleContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),
    ])
    
}
```

UPDATE: In addition to the fact that the original code was adding a color to the `layer` of the `UIView`, the modal was also sub-classing `UITabBarController` and not `UIViewController`, hence why the background color of the modal seemed to be inheriting that of the first VC in the Tab Bar Controller. Changing the superclass to UIViewController ultimately resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a color to the `layer` of the `UIView`. Remove the following line to get the view's background color. Or you can update the layer's color instead.

```
titleContainer.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

To set the color of the previous ViewController's view background you could set it while transitioning as follows:

```
viewController.titleContainer.layer.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor?.cgColor
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comment above. The modal now appears to inherit the background color of the first Tab Bar VC, rather than being transparent.

Comment: That's the result you get when you make a view transparent.

Comment: OK, I see. How do I then make it reflect whatever background color I was on previously? Sorry, if this is a dumb question, I'm relatively new to Swift.

Comment: You could pass the color as a parameter to set it as background color. Check the update.

Comment: The updated suggestion causes the app to crash -- unexpectedly found nil.

Comment: You're probably not initalizing the view controller from storyboard properly.

Answer (score 1):

So your solution is correct the subclassing of your modal controller. In the future, you may want to double check the parent class of your subclasses especially when something off is happening like in your case.

And secondly, another way to help you debug the application is to toggle the attributes of your controller, say. a background color, and if you change your first tab screen's bg color, and the modal copies the color, then you can get to a theory that your modal is somehow getting that attribute from the first tab screen.

Lastly, utilize the Xcode's debugging features. One of those is **Debug View Hierarchy.** - This will give you the hierarchies of your views in 3-dimensional perspective.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select `overCurrentContext` as `modalPresentation` for the vc

```
vc.modalPresentation = overCurrentContext
// present the vc
vc.bColor = UIColor.red
```

and declare this inside the vc

```
var bColor:UIColor!
```

Then set it here

```
titleContainer.layer.backgroundColor = bColor
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason, the modal seems to be inheriting the background color of the first Tab Bar VC. When I switch to another VC with a different background color, and then call the modal, the background color is still the one from the first VC. Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: being transparent means it will show whatever behind it

Comment: Right, but then, why does it always show the background color of the first Tab Bar VC? If I navigate to a different Tab Bar VC with a different color, I still get the background color of the first VC.

Comment: you made it static here `titleContainer.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor` ? send the needed color when you show that vc as a property see edit

Answer (score 0):

Make you super view color to clear for your presenter view controller

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Than write this where ever you want to present your view controller

```
let controllerObject = yourControllor object from the storyboard
controllerObject.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
controllerObject.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
present(controllerOject, animated: true, completion: nil)
```